# Chrome extension async onMessage listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It is very frustrating not to say annoying how incomplete and inaccurate is the documentation of google's products.

I'm trying to build a very simple chrome extension.
From the popup script i need to execute a method from background script.

I've something as simple as:
popup

```
async function login(){
 const result = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "login"});
      console.log(result);
}
```

background

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => async {
    const { action, data, caller } = message;

    console.log("handleAction", action, data, caller);

    if (action === "login")
        sendResponse(await login());
return true;

}
```

as per google chrome documentation
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage

> In the above example, sendResponse() was called synchronously. If you
> want to asynchronously use sendResponse(), add return true; to the onMessage event handler.

i've tried both, return true or return nothing or return sendResponse itself

the result on popup script is always

UNDEFINED

If the login method can't be sync cuz it needs to request the backend, but if i just make a dummy answer and return it sync, then the extension works

the question is

IS IT POSSIBLE TO RETURN ASYNC FROM sendResponse?